# can't insert date into postgresql via eclipselink

Tags: postgresql, datetime, jpa, eclipselink

I have this table in postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE remise
(
id bigserial NOT NULL,
date_remise time without time zone 
)
```

and this code to insert a row into it via eclipselink :

```
Remise rm = new Remise();
rm.setId(1L);
rm.setDateRemise(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); //today
dao.begin();
dao.save(rm);
dao.commit();
```

in the Remise Entity class I have this field with it's getter and setter :

```
@Column(name = "date_remise")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date dateRemise;
```

everything looks ok but the date I get inserted is like that with just time and no date ! 
 in pgAdmin III : "03:16:03" 
 via my application : "Thu Jan 01 03:16:03 WET 1970"

I'm using : Postgresql 9.3, 9.1-901-1.jdbc4, eclipselink 2.5.2.  
Need your help to fix this problem. thanks.

Comment: You mean, you want to persist the date+time? So why are you marking that field with that TemporalType????

Comment: the temporl types we have are TIME, DATE and TIMESTAMP, with oracle I always used TIME and the stored value was both date and time.

Comment: TIME means store Time, TIMESTAMP means store DATE+TIME. It's in the JPA spec

Answer (score 0):

You need to use timestamp without time zone.

time without time zone only stores time portion.

Answer (score 0):

thank you araqnoon for the correct response, just one precision for the mapping of the field it must look like :

```
@Column(name = "date_remise")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateRemise;
```